# Subview access to superview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, superview

I have a scrollView with its content view and finally a subview on the content view.
I would like to stop scrolling `[scrollView scrollEnabled:NO]` from the subview. Can I get at the method?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have Xcode in front of me, but can't you get at the superview with `self.superview` from your subview code?

For instance, like so:

```
[subview.superview scrollEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: so [self.superview scrollEnabled:NO]

Answer (score 0):

To stop scrolling `[scrollView scrollEnabled:NO]` from the subview? Maybe you need a viewController which control the views. Do you clear about the MVC?